# Video quality degrades when uploading to YouTube with variable frame rate

Tags: video, youtube, obs-studio

So I use OBS (latest ver) to record my gameplay on Windows 10.

**OBS settings are:**

- recording format: MP4
- Recording quality: indistinguishable quality, large file size
- Encoder: Software (x264 low CPU usage preset, increases file size)
- Downscale filter: Lanczos (sharpened scaling, 32 samples)
- FPS value for recording: 60
- Base and output resolution are both the same, 1080P and my monitor is
  1080p as well as my in-game resolution.

So when i'm recording from a less demanding games like the new Resident Evil 2 (RE2) the video file looks perfect, both on my computer (using VLC) and on YouTube they look great. I run the game on fixed 60 FPS using V-sync and ultra graphic settings.

the videos i'm talking about:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyrzq-6eeoM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCo2GspC-jE

But, when I record from a more demanding game like Assassin's Creed Odyssey, I can't get a fixed 60 FPS, average is 45 FPS and it varies between 32 to 60 FPS.
after i finish recording i play the video file on VLC and it looks great, just like my gameplay, but when I upload it to YouTube, it looks awful, blurry and so much noise in it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84ZPY1bnj4I

My YouTube channel doesn't have so much subscribers (almost 200) so YouTube doesn't use VP9 to convert my videos, it only uses x264, I don't know it's relatable though.

so my question is, where is the problem exactly? is it YouTube's fault converting my videos so poorly? because they look fine on my computer when i play them.

Or

is it my fault and i'm doing something wrong in the settings? if so what should i change?

**PS:**

I've tried setting the recording FPS in OBS to 30 FPS but the gameplay looked so slow on YouTube and on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your fault neither YouTube, it's about video compression.

To simplify, when you want to encode a video, you will have a base image every few seconds (5 for example) and to have the intermediate images you are saving movement to reduce data flow (and file size by the way).
To reduce more the data, you can approach movement by linear function and represent movement by key frames each 2 or 3 frames. When you have full FPS, it's perfect, but when you have less, you will regularly have two identical images and for the movement it's like stopping movement then resume it. It cost mush more data to code less frame rate because you will have to use much more key frames to code frame stop and resume.

That's why your quality decrease if you're not running your game at 60fps.

But there is solutions, the first is to record at a frame rate inferior to your game. The second is to tell your editing software to interpolate missing frames rather than display a the last frame.

Comment: Please read the question again: "after i finish recording i play the video file on VLC and it looks great, just like my gameplay, but when I upload it to YouTube, it looks awful, blurry and so much noise in it" – so it's not about the game not running at 60fps

Comment: It's because your recording software is not compressing much your video, then it's not visible. But YouTube as an online streaming platform, have to compress much more and the problem appear. I got the same problem before, my recording was 50Mbps (nearly no compression) and YouTube no more than 10Mbps.

Comment: Hi, I tried recording at lower FPS and the result wasn't so good, but about the second option i think i can do that but need more info. so i have Adobe premiere pro, it has options for time interpolation and they are (frame sampling by default, frame blending and optical flow), AFAIK optical flow is used when video file has lower FPS than the target FPS we set at export, so i think i should use this one, *but* , will it actually help? because the video file the OBS gives me is already 60 FPS with 100mbps bitrate, so if i convert it to 50mbps 60FPS x264 MP4 in premiere, the end result will...

Comment: will look better on Youtube? (with optical flow of course)

Comment: I think the answer is now in the hand of video processing specialists (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/) i don't think you will find an how to for premiere here. The point is to detect when you have two identical frames and replace it by an interpolated one. But i'm pretty sure that's will help YouTube to compress the video in a better way (avoiding representing still frames).

Comment: You can also search for a setting in your recording software to allow non constant frame rate in output video file (these kind of codex exist and common).

Comment: I looked it up and it seems like VFR formats have issues with audio/video syncing. it's a shame YouTube as a big resourceful company does this to videos.  i will post the question on that other forum as well, if nothing works i should consider using Twich instead, hopefully they handle videos in a more professional way and won't discriminate against their users.

Comment: Please do not re-post your question. You can flag for it to be migrated. Duplicating questions across the networks is not allowed.